# error when try to install flask in the virtual enviroment

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, flask, virtualenv

I just configure the environment to develop the flask based web app. All the things goes smoothly, but when I run my hello world app, the python interpret tell me no module named flask:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

but I seriously install flask.

When I get the error, i just run the command in the virtual environment, `sudo pip install flask`. Then, the console show the message:

```
(venv)ubuntu@localhost:/var/www/demoapp$ sudo pip install flask
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flask in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2>=2.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): itsdangerous>=0.21 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): markupsafe in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask)
Cleaning up...
```

Who can tell me how can I run my hello world flask app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

> $ sudo pip install...

system pip will be used. So to install flask in current environment just run

> $ pip install ...
>   or as:
>   $ /path/to/venv/bin/pip install ...

Or make your venv able to load global system packages by parameter --system-site-packages, while configure virtual environment.

Comment: thanks ...so so so muck. got it. resolved this issue.

Answer (score -1):

If you are having the same trouble even if you have your virtualenv running, just make sure you didn't accidentally delete the files and attempt to execute pip in that folder you created for your venv...  Like I did.  :D